# three.js trackball control without the roll

Tags: three.js

Does anybody know if/how the trackball control can be modified to keep the horizon level but still allow you to rotate around and over an object?

By setting axis.x and axis.z to 0 it stops the roll but also stops the ability to rotate over the object.

The orbit control is close to what I am looking for but does not have the ability to pan.

Any help?

Comment: `OrbitControls` now supports panning in three.js r.58.

Comment: I think WestLangley's comment should be converted to an answer so he can be awarded the bounty -- it seems to answer the question, as far as I can tell, OrbitControls has all the functionality of Trackball controls, except there is no roll, hence the horizon will stay level.

Comment: I agree with this although I know not how to convert his comment to an answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's been awhile since this question was asked, but I ran into the same problem and didn't find much discussion online, so I thought I'd post my solution.

If you must use TrackballControls and you want to a flat horizon, you can simply edit the TrackballControls.js library by adding the following line to the end of the 'this.rotateCamera' method

this.object.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
This locks the camera up direction in the (0,1,0) direction (i.e in the y direction). The entire modified method function would then read:

```
this.rotateCamera = function () {

var angle = Math.acos( _rotateStart.dot( _rotateEnd ) / _rotateStart.length() / _rotateEnd.length() );

if ( angle ) {

    var axis = ( new THREE.Vector3() ).crossVectors( _rotateStart, _rotateEnd ).normalize();
        quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

    angle *= _this.rotateSpeed;

    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, -angle );

    _eye.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
    _this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

    _rotateEnd.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

    if ( _this.staticMoving ) {

        _rotateStart.copy( _rotateEnd );

    } else {

        quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, angle * ( _this.dynamicDampingFactor - 1.0 ) );
        _rotateStart.applyQuaternion( quaternion );

    }

}

// Lock the camera up direction
this.object.up = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);

};
```

Comment: Assuming it works, do not instantiate a new object. `this.object.up.set( 0, 1, 0 );`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, working on the math behind it still.
[edit] I use `camera.lookAt(someObj)` first, then this.

```
camera.rotation.z = Math.sin(camera.rotation.y)/3.5
```

Answer (score -1):

To build upon [WestLangley comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838308/three-js-trackball-control-without-the-roll#comment25140173_12838308), enabling [screenSpacePanning](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.screenSpacePanning) on OrbitControls, gives you equivalent functionality to TrackballControls without roll.

```
  let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.screenSpacePanning = true;
```